# How to expand label height in KivyMD?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to make the label height dynamically expanded depending on the size of text inside. I tried this:

```
from kivymd.label import MDLabel

label = MDLabel(
    text="My looooooooooong text",
    width=500,
    size_hint=(None, None)
)
```

But the height of this label is fixed and the text is shown deformed. How to make the height expanded?

I am using Python 3 and KivyMD library.

Answer (score 0):

The `MDLabel` class inherits from `kivy.uix.Label`. All arguments you'll pass normally to `kivy.uix.Label` can be passed to the `MDLabel`. 
Checking the constructor for `MDLabel` validates this.

To make a label with unlimited height, you'll construct the Label like so:

```
label = MDLabel(text='My looooooooooong text', text_size=(500, None))
```

#### Reference:

- https://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/uix/label.html
- https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/label.py

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. The text is still deformed.

Comment: which widget contains the label?

Comment: BoxLayout contains the label.

Comment: You may be able to fix the text with the right `size_hint_y` on the `BoxLayout` and `pos_hint` on the `MDLabel`. Can you share a screenshot of how the widget renders?